# Can an Evil Sorcerer cast Holy Cascade?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e

[Holy Cascade](http://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=151) has the trait "Good", but unlike [Divine Lance](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=84) for example, it is silent about your or your god's alignment.
The only possibly relevant section is Anathema by Clerics, but even Sorcerers with Bloodlines using the *divine* spell list have nothing like that.

Based on that, even Evil Sorcerers should be able to cast Holy Cascade. Is that right?

Comment: Can you include a restatement of your question in the body? It seems like you are answering your own question, but I'm not sure.

Comment: So are you asking about neutral or evil sorcerers?

Comment: both, but I simplified the question

Comment: There's always Un-holy Crusades.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### That seems fine

Nothing in the [Spell rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=259) nor the [Good](http://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=83) (or [Evil](http://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=64), for that matter) Trait prevent spellcasters from engaging in spells that do not line up with their alignment. The Magic and Morality sidebar in [Enchantment](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=265) notes that using the spell may affect your alignment, largely depending on application/intent.

> While magic allows you to perform wondrous acts in the game, it can be used for terrible purposes. While some spells are obviously vile or have the evil trait and a direct connection to the profane, other spells can be used for good or ill. Using magic does not free you from the morality of the outcome.
>
> [...] Using a spell for an evil purpose can cause a player character’s alignment to shift to evil, with the ultimate judgment of whether a player is using a spell for an evil purpose left up to the GM.

Depending on your group, it may be worth checking with your GM (especially if you have Demonic or Diabolic Bloodline) due to narrative consistency, but **there is no mechanical reason it doesn't work.**